# How to make this tooltip overlay parent div?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-3

[JFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FR3yv/1/)

As you can see on the jsfiddle link, I have a button with tooltip display on mouse hover. The problem is that tooltip area isn't overlaying the parent div and will display only inside the div.

I know that if I remove `.panel-heading {
    overflow:hidden;
  }` this will work but I need this css to stay for some of the responsive issues. I have tried adding `.toolt {
    overflow:visible;
}` to tooltip div but it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change container of tooltip

```
$('.toolt span').tooltip({container:'body'});
```